# mono osx has warning for non-7 bit chars, interpreting using MacOS Roman encoding for now

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I have downloaded and installed latest MONO MDK for OSX, I tried to run the demo c# program as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HelloWorld : Form
  {
     static public void Main ()
     {
        Application.Run (new HelloWorld ());
     }

     public HelloWorld ()
       {
          Text = "哈羅您好";
          // Text = "Hello Mono World";
       }
}
```

I did 
mcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet
mono hello.exe

But I am getting non-readable chinese characters and the console is output the the following warning:
2014-12-02 17:49:04.156 mono[1719:240393] WARNING: CFSTR("\37777777745\37777777623\37777777610\37777777747\37777777676\37777777605\37777777746\37777777602\37777777650\37777777745\37777777645\37777777675") has non-7 bit chars, interpreting using MacOS Roman encoding for now, but this will change. Please eliminate usages of non-7 bit chars (including escaped characters above \177 octal) in CFSTR().

Can someone help me to display the correct Chinese characters? DO I need to install anything? Thanks.

P.S. If the code is

```
Text = "Hello Mono World";
```

then it works with no warning.

Comment: Really, no one has any clue? Not even the mono development team? Is there a problem with mono supporting unicode encoding? This is very disappointing to know mono can't be use for none English development.